# fstream << operate not writing entire output

Tags: c++, stream, fstream

Everthing goes well until the f << "string" << temp_int << endl; statement
   get different results with different openmodes, either doesn't write at all or writes the first two chars of "NumberSaves"

```
unsigned int temp_int = 0;
 fstream f("resources/saveData/Player/savelog.txt");
 if (!f)
{
    cout << "error accessing savelist" << endl;
}
else
{
    string skip;
    std::stringstream iss;
    string line;
    readVarFromFile(f, iss, skip, line, { &temp_int });      //check how many saves currently
    temp_int += 1;                                           //increment number of saves by 1
    f.seekp(ios_base::beg);
    cout << "Write position: " << f.tellp() << endl;         //check stream is at beginning
    f << "<NumberSaves>" << temp_int << endl;                //truncate <NumberSaves> 'x' with <NumberSaves> 'x + 1'
    cout << "Write position: " << f.tellp() << endl;         //position suggests the entire string has been written, only two characters have been
    if (!f)
    {
        cout << "ERROR";
    }

    f.seekp(ios_base::end); 
    f << currentPlayer->getName();                           //append players name to end of file
}
```

desired output is as follows

> NumberSaves 2
>   player
>   anotherplayer

current output

> Nu
>   player

Comment: What is `readVarFromFile()`? Provide a [MCVE] please.

Comment: Realize that seeking to a position in a file is best suited for files opened in binary mode.  If the file is opened in text  mode, you will not get the desired results using `seekp`, `tellp`, etc. due to the new-line and eof translation being done.

Comment: it is a function i made that is not part of the problem, sorry if it caused confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use seekp properly like this:

```
os.seekp(0, std::ios_base::end); // means bring me to 0 from the end of file.
```

look at the example code in
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp

std::ios_base::end is a direction not an absolute position. It is just an enum value. The value is probably 2 and that is why it brings you to position 2 inside the file.

Comment: but say if there are 5 saved players (all on seperate lines), I cannot continue the write straight after "Number of Saves" because it will overwrite a player